# mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-api, laravel-relations

These are tables i get data

```
Student
-------------
id
sex
```

```
AcademicLevel
--------------
id
name
```

```
Session
-------
id
term_id
start_date
end_date
session_type
```

here's the relationship table

```
Enrollment
----------
id
student_id
session_id
academic_level_id
program_id
```

**Relationship** 
student, academic level, session hasMany enrollment

```
class Enrollment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'enrollment';
    protected $fillable = [
        'session_id',
        'student_id',
        'program_id',
        'academic_level_id',
    ];

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Session', 'session_id');
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student', 'student_id');
    }

    public function program()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Program', 'program_id');
    }

    public function academicLevel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AcademicLevel', 'academic_level_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    const MALE = 'male';
    const FEMALE = 'female';
    protected $table = 'students';
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'middle_name',
        'suffix',
        'email',
        'student_number',
        'sex',
        'birthdate',
        'lrn',
        "profile_picture"
    ];
    protected $appends = ['allow_delete'];

    public function enrollment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Enrollment', 'student_id', 'id');
    }
    
    public function getAllowDeleteAttribute()
    {
        return !$this->enrollment()->exists();
    }

    public function getIsEnrolledAttribute()
    {
        return Enrollment::where('student_id', $this->id)
            ->whereHas('session', function($query) {
                $query->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"))
                    ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));
            })
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

Here's where i fetch records of total students enrolled in current date and must be groupby sex but the record must be groupby academic level name (ex. elementary, junior high school, senior high school, college depending on the school).

```
public function countStudentEnrollmentBySexAndAcademicLevel()
    {
        AcademicLevel::with('enrollment', function ($query) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now());
            $query->withCount('students as female students', function ($query) {
                $query->where('sex', 'female');
            })->withCount('students as male_students', function ($query) {
                $query->where('sex', 'male');
            });
        })->get();
    }
```

here's my endpoint

```
Route::get('/count-student-enrollment-by-sex-and-academic-level', [EnrollmentController::class, 'countStudentEnrollmentBySexAndAcademicLevel']);
```

but i get this error
[image]

Comment: Can u please change this `students as female students` to `students as female_students` ?

Comment: Also please provide *trace* list

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).  The full trace would probably give you more hints about where the problem is, but we can't see it.  [The docs for `withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) suggest you need to use an array for the parameter when using a query: `->withCount(['students as female_students' => function (...) { ... }])`.  And as mentiond you have a typo in your `AS female students` SQL.